# Comparing object references in Vala

Tags: vala

In vala, `==` compares the content for string type. I want to compare two objects (including strings) reference like java's `obj == obj2`. I couldn't find a document about it.

How to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare Strings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: My question is about the Vala, not Java.

Comment: Strings aren't objects in Vala, so what is the context in which you are trying to do a comparison?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the underlying byte array to compare it by reference.

```
string a = "a";
unowned string b = a;

assert (a.data == b.data);
```

More generally, comparing references is not relevant because string can only have a single owner. If you have two strong references on `string` objects, they are guarantee to be different.

This is why `b` has been assigned with a weak reference from `a`, otherwise a copy would be made.